# Configuring services / service factories in Equinox

Tags: eclipse, osgi, equinox, apache-felix

I have an OSGi bundle in Apache Felix with a ManagedServiceFactory, which requires configuration data.

In Felix, it works fine, I use either the webconsole or I add a [factorypid].cfg file to the watched directory.

My question is: How should I do that in Equinox, specifically from an Eclipse OSGi launch configuration?

I could add Felix fileinstall (I guess it also works with Equinox?) but I suspect there is an obvious way to do that I'm missing.

Anybody have a clue?

regards, Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Configuration Admin](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/cm/package-summary.html) is intended to be a general decoupling mechanism, so your application shouldn't really worry about the way ConfigAdmin gets its data: you can even use the API to set your configuration, if you require.

If you like the way FileInstall works, that's probably the way to go, there is nothing Felix-specific about it.

**edit**: or, more to the point, if you have a setup of bundles that you like, there should be no need to change it when changing frameworks. Hence, try to stay away from framework-specific properties.

Comment: Ok, that will work. It was more of an Eclipse question than anything else. I'm just surprised that in Eclipse launch configurations, with all its options, there is no possibility to add some configuration to a run/debug session.